# leetcode algorithm edgecase issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

**I am doing the following problem:**

> Given the array candies and the integer extraCandies, where candies[i]
> represents the number of candies that the ith kid has.
>
> For each kid check if there is a way to distribute extraCandies among
> the kids such that he or she can have the greatest number of candies
> among them. Notice that multiple kids can have the greatest number of
> candies.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: candies = [2,3,5,1,3], extraCandies = 3 Output:
> [true,true,true,false,true]  Explanation:  Kid 1 has 2 candies and if
> he or she receives all extra candies (3) will have 5 candies --- the
> greatest number of candies among the kids.  Kid 2 has 3 candies and if
> he or she receives at least 2 extra candies will have the greatest
> number of candies among the kids.  Kid 3 has 5 candies and this is
> already the greatest number of candies among the kids.  Kid 4 has 1
> candy and even if he or she receives all extra candies will only have
> 4 candies.  Kid 5 has 3 candies and if he or she receives at least 2
> extra candies will have the greatest number of candies among the kids.
> Example 2:
>
> Input: candies = [4,2,1,1,2], extraCandies = 1 Output:
> [true,false,false,false,false]  Explanation: There is only 1 extra
> candy, therefore only kid 1 will have the greatest number of candies
> among the kids regardless of who takes the extra candy. Example 3:
>
> Input: candies = [12,1,12], extraCandies = 10 Output:
> [true,false,true]
>
> Constraints:
>
> 2 <= candies.length <= 100 1 <= candies[i] <= 100 1 <= extraCandies <=
> 50

here is my code and below my code is the error I am getting but it seems right?

```
const kidsWithCandies = (candies, extraCandies) => {
    let candiesTwo = [...candies]
    candiesTwo = candiesTwo.sort()
    
    let arr = []
    let highestNum = candiesTwo[candiesTwo.length -1]
    
    for(let i = 0; i < candies.length; i++) { 
        if(candies[i] + extraCandies >= highestNum) { 
            arr.push(true)
        }  else { 
          arr.push(false)
        }
    }
    return arr
}
```

**I am getting**

```
71 / 103 test cases passed.
Status: Wrong Answer
Submitted: 3 minutes ago
Input:
[1,10,10,3]
1
Output:
[false,true,true,true]
Expected:
[false,true,true,false]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a compare function to sort numbers or they will be in alpha order. By default, the sort() method sorts the values as strings in alphabetical and ascending order.

Simple example

```js
const candies = [4, 11, 22, 2, 1];

console.log('No compare function:', JSON.stringify([...candies].sort()))

candies.sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log('With compare function:', JSON.stringify(candies))
```

Answer (score 1):

By default sort method sorts items alphabetically.
You should update from

```
candiesTwo = candiesTwo.sort()
```

to

```
candiesTwo.sort((a, b) => a-b);
```

for numerical sort.

Comment: Or find maximum number by using Math.max(...candies) instead, however you pointed out the actual problem in the solution above.

Comment: Thank you. This is definitely nice to know for the future. I solved it also by using Math.max(...candies)

Comment: Math.max(...candies) works fine for most cases.
But in edge case like candies length is very huge, it won't work.
Of course for this problem it's fine (<100)
@stephen1993

Answer (score 1):

If we'd use `sort`, the time complexity would be an order of `N Log N`. Here is an `O(N)` solution:

```
const kidsWithCandies = (candies, extraCandies) => {
    let maxCandies = 0;
    const greatest = [];

    for (const candy of candies) {
        (candy > maxCandies) && (maxCandies = candy);
    }

    for (let index = 0; index < candies.length; ++index) {
        greatest.push(candies[index] + extraCandies >= maxCandies);
    }
    return greatest;
};
```